# jQuery dialog jumping to full page in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a dialog with a WebGrid that displays a list of items:

```
 @if (Model.ItemsByLocation != null)
{
    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "table",
    fillEmptyRows: true,
    headerStyle: "header",
    footerStyle: "footer",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    firstText: "<<First",
    previousText: "<Prev",
    nextText: "Next>",
    lastText: "Last>>",
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid"},
    columns: new []
    {
        //grid.Column("ItemNumber", "Item"),
        grid.Column(header: "Item Number", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink((string)item.ItemNumber, "ShowItem", "Inventory", new { id = item.ItemNumber.ToString()}, new {onclick = "GetItemDetails(" + item.ItemNumber.ToString() + ");"})),
        grid.Column("ItemDescription","Desc"),
        grid.Column("ItemSerialNumber","SN"),
        grid.Column("itemLocationSite","Site"),
        grid.Column("ItemLocationBuilding","Bldg"),
        grid.Column("ItemLocationFloor","Flr"),
        grid.Column("ItemLocationOffice","Off"),
        grid.Column("ItemTypeDescription","Type"),
        grid.Column("FirstName","First"),
        grid.Column("LastName","Last")

    }) 

}
else {
 <p><i>No item to display</i></p>   
}
```

This is a dialog itself from another page - no problem with this.  When I click on the link the JS function is called:

```
 function GetItemDetails(id) {
    var test = id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("ShowItem")?id=' + id,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divDetails").html(data);
            $("#divDetails").dialog("open");
            $("#divDetails").show();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

This responds with another dialog on top of the first dialog, but only for a second or two and then both dialog close and the data in the second dialog is displayed full page in the browser.  Any ideas why this is?

This is the dialog for the details:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    //debugger;

    $("#divDetails").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 'auto',
        resizable: true,
        title: 'Item Details',
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        show: {
            effect: 'drop', direction: 'up'
        },
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {

                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }).prev("ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "#FF3300");
    $(".dialog").click(function () {
        $("#divDetails").dialog("open");
    });

});

<div id="divDetails" style="display:none" class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header">

 </div>
```

I put some breakpoints in the code and after the second dialog is displayed the controller Index function is called.  How does that happen?  It does this if I remove the ShowItem from the link,  But if I put that back in, it calls the ShowItem function twice.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know what the problem was but if I change the webgrid column to this, it works just fine:

```
 grid.Column(header: "Item Number", format:@<a href="#" onclick="GetItemDetails(@item.ItemNumber.ToString());return false;">@item.ItemNumber.ToString()</a>),
```